# difference between multithreading and multiprocessing threadpool?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have list of 20 items in file A and these are passed to file B for processing and the result to be returned.

Currently I am doing with multithreading. And came accross concept of  threadpool and multiprocessing and was wondering whats the difference between multithreading and threadpool and will my program benefit from threading or threadpool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> whats the difference between multithreading and threadpool

Multithreading is the ability of a CPU to execute multiple processes/threads concurrently. See [multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)) for details.
A thread pool is a group of threads which are created in advance which you can reuse over and over to do tasks. See [What is a thread pool?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173575/what-is-a-thread-pool) for more information.

> will my program benefit from threading or threadpool?

From your description, you only have 2 files, A and B and there are only 20 items you need to process. Most likely threading and thread pools will provide no benefit. If the processing is extremely io intensive or cpu intensive, you may benefit from threading, but you have to explain what processing is going on to answer that question. As for a thread pool though, you will not benefit either way. Thread pools are used because creating threads is very expensive. They eliminate having to create/destroy threads multiple times. However, your program only has two files, so there will be no benefit.